# project won't link in release mode error lnk1181

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I have a project that i can compile and link in debug mode, but i am not able to link in release mode. I can compile, but not link.

The error i get is

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\Release\Class1.obj'
```

I am using MS Visual Studio 2008, Visual C++. Is something missing in project properties, any ideas?

EDIT: If i delete '*.obj' files in Debug folder, then build in Debug mode, it generates those files and builds. How do i get it to generate the files in Release mode?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you do "Rebuild" rather than "Build"?

Comment: Yes, i get the error whether it is a "Build" or "Rebuild".

Comment: Take a look here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815645 - maybe you have some spaces in your path?

Comment: If i delete '*.obj' files in Debug folder, then build in Debug mode, it generates those files and builds. How do i get it to generate the files in Release mode?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was toying with project settings, comparing to debug mode. I made the following changes and i can link now.

Optimization = Disabled (/Od)

Inline function Expansion = Default

Generate Preprocessed File = No

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reducing the optimization level from Ob2 to Ob1 ("Maximum speed" to "Minimum size") helped me, like gorkem described.

Comment: This does not add any new information. Please consider upvoting the correct anwer rather than answering and referenicing the answer.